# Is an assignment inside ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent threadsafe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Consider the following implementation of some kind of fixed size cache, that allows lookup by an integer handle:

```
static class HandleCache {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private final Map<Data, Integer> handles = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final Data[] array = new Data[100_000];

    int getHandle(Data data) {
        return handles.computeIfAbsent(data, k -> {
            int i = counter.getAndIncrement();
            if (i >= array.length) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("array overflow");
            }
            array[i] = data;
            return i;
        });

    }

    Data getData(int handle) {
        return array[handle];
    }
}
```

There is an array store inside the compute function, which is not synchronized in any way. Would it be allowed by the java memory model for other threads to read a null value from this array later on?

**PS:** Would the outcome change if the id returned from `getHandle` was stored in a `final` field and only accessed through this field from other threads?

Comment: You should use an [AtomicReferenceArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html) for your `Data[] array` to avoid race conditions.

Comment: You probably may know this, your `mappingFunction` is changing state outside of the map (`int i = counter.getAndIncrement()`) 
so that it is possible that `array` may contain "gaps".

If you call `getData()` with the handle provided by the current value of `counter` you may get in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read access isn't thread safe. You could make it thread safe indirectly however it's likely to be brittle.  I would implemented it in a much simpler way and only optimise it later should it prove to a performance problem. e.g. because you see it in a profiler for a realistic test.

```
static class HandleCache {
    private final Map<Data, Integer> handles = new HashMap<>();
    private final List<Data> dataByIndex = new ArrayList<>();

    synchronized int getHandle(Data data) {
        Integer id = handles.get(data);
        if (id == null) {
             id = handles.size();
             handles.put(data, id);
             dataByIndex.add(id);
        }
        return id;
    }

    synchronized Data getData(int handle) {
        return dataByIndex.get(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indirectly due to internal synchronized block in ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: @user7 that creates a write barrier. You can also create a read barrier by adding a volatile field you always read first, but it's code easily broken in the future.

Comment: Agree, sometimes I need a reminder to not overcomplicate things. And synchronized probably does not have such a high overhead compared to using both AtomicInteger and ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann AI is more light weight but CHM is much the same as sync unless highly contended.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you determine the index for the array read from the value of `counter` than yes - you may get a null read

The simplest example (there are others) is a follows:

T1 calls `getHandle(data)` and is suspended just after `int i = counter.getAndIncrement();`
T2 calls `handles[counter.get()]` and reads null.

You should be able to easily verify this with a strategically placed `sleep` and two threads.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this map.

The documentation's reference to blocking refers only to update operations on the `Map`, so if any other thread attempts to access `array` directly (rather than through an update operation on the `Map`), there can be race conditions and `null` can be read.

Comment: I believe it is because there is no *happens before* guarantee here. Will making `array` volatile solve this?

Comment: @user7 Admittedly, I'm not the most knowledgeable on concurrency, so I can't really say.  I'd imagine that synchronizing on `array` would prevent any other thread from accessing it while it is being written to, but I agree that another thread can attempt to access `array` at any time, so that may even be pointless.

Comment: I guess it is more to do with what will happen after the lambda block is completed and a thread access `array[i]` where `i` is the integer returned from `getHandle`.

Comment: @user7 NOTE: You can make the `array` field volatile, but you can't make access to the array volatile.  To make a field `volatile` it can't be `final` as this makes no sense.

Comment: This is also my understanding from the ConcurrentHashMap documentation, it only gives guarantees for the map itself, and so the code is not safe in general. However, my idea is that other threads would only access the data using handles that were previously returned from `getHandle`, so if such a handle is published to another thread in a threadsafe way, this should ensure a happens-before relationship with the array write, right?